# How to test if a RegExp contains capturing groups in its definition?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find two `RegExp`:

1. One to test whether another `RegExp` contains capturing groups, like in `/ab(c)d/`
2. Same as 1., but only detecting named capturing groups, like `/ab(?<name>c)d/`

These "meta"-regexes would check the [`source` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/source) of a regex.

Here is my best attempt for 1: `/(?<!\\)\((?!\?:)/`.
The idea is to look for an opening parenthesis not preceded by `\` and not followed by `?:` (which would make it a non-capturing group). But this has false positives (`/c[z(a]d/` for example), and false negatives `/a\\(b)/`.

My attempt at 2. follows the same logic and has thus the same flaws: `/(?<!\\)\(\?<(?![=!])/`

Any idea on how to do this properly? Thank you.

Comment: The OP's 1st attempt (the one for case one) fails for e.g. `/a\(b(c\(a\))\)d/` where the capturing group is placed into escaped opening and closing parenthesis. A regex which manages to avoid escaped parenthesis as well as non capturing groups `(?:)` and lookarounds like `(?<)`, `(?=)` and `(?!)` is more complex and might look like [`/(?<!\\)\((?!\?[:<=!]).*(?<!\\)\)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/JVoOlX/1).

Comment: The example you give is actually properly detected by my attempt. Problems are with opening parentheses after escaped backslash, or in character classes, which remains a problem even with your more complex solution. It's also not necessary to check if the capturing group is syntactically valid (like looking for a closing parenthesis), that will be checked by JS itself. We can assume that the regexes to test are always valid.

Comment: the OP's 1st attempt does not avoid ... _"lookarounds like `(?<)`, `(?=)` and `(?!)`"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex that besides spotting capture groups, also captures escape pairs (`\\.`) and character classes `\[(?:\\.|.)*?\]` (also aware of escape characters), so to avoid false positives/negatives. Then loop over the matches to spot the good matches.

The below snippet returns the number of anonymous capture groups and the names of the named capture groups:

```js
const reParser = /\\.|\[(?:\\.|.)*?\]|(\()(?!\?)|\(\?<([^=!][^>]*)/g;
function captureGroups(regex) {
    const names = [];
    let numAnonymous = 0;
    for (const [match, anon, name] of regex.source.matchAll(reParser)) {
        if (name) names.push(name);
        else if (anon) numAnonymous++;
    }
    return { numAnonymous, names };
}

// Example run
console.log(captureGroups(/test[12\](3]*(?<xy>((\.))?)/g));
```

If you only need to know the fact whether there is a capture group, then you could first remove those escape pairs and character classes from the regex and replace them with a single character. Then remains to recognise the capture group pattern:

```js
function hasCaptureGroups(regex) {
    const simpler = regex.source.replace(/\\.|\[(?:\\.|.)*?\]/g, "x");
    return {
        hasAnonymous: /\([^?]/.test(simpler),
        hasNamed: /\(\?</.test(simpler)
    };
}

// Example run
console.log(hasCaptureGroups(/test[12\](3]*(?<xy>((\.))?)/g));
```

To get this done with just a regular expression and no replacement, you need to focus on matching an input that does **not** have the capture group, and then negate that -- that can be done with a negative look-ahead at the very first position, scanning the complete input:

```js
const reAnonymousGroup = /^(?!(\\.|\[(?:\\.|.)*?\]|[^(]|\(\?)*$)/;
const reNamedGroup     = /^(?!(\\.|\[(?:\\.|.)*?\]|[^(]|\([^?]|\(\?[^<])*$)/;

// Example run
const regex = /test[12\](3]*(?<xy>((\.))?)/g;
console.log("has anonymous group:", reAnonymousGroup.test(regex.source));
console.log("has named group:", reNamedGroup.test(regex.source));
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to write this regex to simply evaluate to `true` if there is a capturing group, and false otherwise? Right now, it also tests `true` on double backslashes.

Comment: That regex is not intended for a boolean result. You could just check the returned object to see if the first count is zero and the inner array is empty. But I have added a version that just returns two booleans. See addition to my answer.

Comment: This looks really great and solves the issue indeed. Thanks. Just curious if it's possible to solve it without the overhead of replace and additional regex checks.